# How to get the base address of a pointer to a dynamically allocated object

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have defined a struct above `main()` called "Pieces"

```
struct Pieces {
    char *word;
    int jump;
}
```

In my `main()` I have:

```
int main() {
    Pieces *pieceptr;
    readFile(preceptor);

    cout << (*pieceptr).word << endl; //SEGFAULT occurs here

    return 0;
}
```

And in `readFile()` I have:

```
void readFile(Pieces *&pieceptr) {

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("data");
    int pieceCount;
    if(fin.is_open()) {
        fin >> pieceCount;

        pieceptr = new Pieces[pieceCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < pieceCount; i++) {
            char *tempWord = new char[20];
            fin >> tempWord >> (*pieceptr).jump;
            (*pieceptr).word = new char[stringLength(tempWord)];
            stringCopy((*pieceptr).word, tempWord);
            delete []tempWord; 
            tempWord = NULL;
            pieceptr++;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

The constraints for this project are:

- Create my own string functions
- Square brackets should only be used when declaring or deallocating an array dynamically.
- Do not use pointer arithmetic, besides ++ and -- or setting back to home pointer.
- Do not use arrow (->) notation with your pointers.

I have tested the `readFile()` function extensively and it is functioning as I want it to (it populates the Pieces array correctly), but after I call `readFile()` in `main()` I need to access the first element of the array again. As the code is now, I get a segfault due to the fact that the pointer has been incremented out of the bounds of the array. How would I reset the pointer to point back to the first element inside the array without using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: Make a copy of the `pieceptr` pointer, and increment that when reading. There's no way to "reset the pointer"; you could decrement the pointer by the number of items you read, but `readFile` does not return that information.

Comment: You are probably not allocating space for a null terminator in `new char[stringLength(tempWord)]` (assuming `stringLength()` behaves like `strlen()`).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thank you but I should have mentioned we are not able to use -> notation in the project either. I have updated the post.

Comment: Just a rhetorical question: "Do not use arrow (->) notation with your pointers" - I don't understand what the educational benefit of this is (unlike making you write your own string functions).  Why would an instructor impose this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple pointers can point to same point of memory. Pointers can also be copied. Easiest solution to yours problem is to create another pointer and do all increasing on it.

```
void readFile(Pieces *&pieceptr) {

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("data");
    int pieceCount;
    if(fin.is_open()) {
        fin >> pieceCount;

        pieceptr = new Pieces[pieceCount];
        Pieces* pieceIterator = pieceptr;
        for (int i = 0; i < pieceCount; i++) {
            char *tempWord = new char[20];
            fin >> tempWord >> (*pieceIterator).jump;
            (*pieceIterator).word = new char[stringLength(tempWord)];
            stringCopy((*pieceIterator).word, tempWord);
            delete []tempWord; 
            tempWord = NULL;
            pieceIterator++;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Oh I hadn't thought of that. Everything is working correctly now. Thanks for your answer.